# How to check if NFT is in a specific wallet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, cryptocurrency, wallet, nft

I need to check if a specific NFT is in a specific wallet, there is an API or a way to do it programmatically?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the NFT is published onchain and its collection contract implements the [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) standard, you can call the `ownerOf()` function (defined in the standard) on the collection contract.

Example using [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/):

```
const collection = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJson, collectionAddress);
const owner = await collection.methods.ownerOf(tokenId).call();
return owner == desiredAddress;
```

---

For the [ERC-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) standard, you can use the `balanceOf()` function.

```
const balance = await collection.methods.balanceOf(owner, ,tokenId).call();
return balance > 0;
```

Comment: It's ERC-1155 standard, it works in the same way?

Comment: @EdoardoCortese ERC-1155 doesn't define the `ownerOf()` function but you can use its `balanceOf()`. I expanded my answer with example of the ERC-1155 retrieval.